# Debugging Javascript / AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, debugging, ujs

I saw a lot of questions and answers on how to debug javascript with chrome, firebug etc...

but this all involves a pre-loaded js file.

Is there a way to debug (step by step, not with alerts) a js script that comes as a response to a Rails AJAX request?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have access to edit the file that Rails returns, you can temporarily insert a `debugger;` statement.

Then, when you have your browser's debugging console open as you receive the AJAX response, JS execution will halt and you can step through execution in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your response to include the `debugger` keyword it should hit that as a break point. You can ONLY examine the results of the ajax call from within the success handler itself. So in this case the response would be:

```
var test = "it isn't working";
var response = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'jquerydemo.php', 
    success: function(data, textStatus, xhr){
            debugger;
            //alert("it's working");   
        },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
            debugger;
            //alert("Error detected");
        }
 });
```

Obviously don't forget to remove that when it goes live. :D